# Power BI: Override the slicer value in Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table which includes products, where each products can have different attributes and prices. Such as this:

| Product | Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 10000 | 20$ |
| B | 10 | 10000 | 15$ |
| C | 10 | 10000 | 23$ |
| A | 20 | 10000 | 30$ |
| B | 20 | 10000 | 32$ |
| C | 20 | 10000 | 33$ |
| A | 10 | 20000 | 34$ |
| B | 10 | 20000 | 44$ |
| C | 10 | 20000 | 55$ |
| A | 30 | 10000 | 100$ |
| B | 30 | 10000 | 222$ |
| C | 30 | 10000 | 230$ |

In the Power BI report, there is one slicer for Attribute 1 and one slicer for Attribute 2, both allow single select. The user selects a combination of the attributes (1 from each) and the 3 products are shown with their prices.

Let's consider Attribute 1 = 10 and Attribute 2 = 10000 in the slicers, therefore products A, B, C are showing in the table with their relative prices.

I have a measure which calculates an **Alternative Attribute 1**. Would it be possible to show an "Alternate Price" in the same table, which uses the Alternative Attribute 1 as the slicer, and get's the equivalent price for Product A, B and C, keeping Attribute 2 slicer same as selected by the user.

Let's say the calculated Aternative Attribute 1 was 20, then, I would like to show the Alternative prices next to the prices for each product (with the user selected filter) using Attribute 1 = 20 but and Attribute 2 same as selected by the slicer.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
_measureWithAlternativeAttribute1 =
VAR _1 =
    MAX ( 'Table 1'[Product] )
VAR _2 =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table 1'[Price] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table 1' ),
            'Table 1'[Attribute 1] = [Alternative Attribute 1]
                && 'Table 1'[Product] = _1
        )
    )
RETURN
    _2
```

[image: Solution]